# Getting started with Sync Framework and SQlite

Tags: sqlite, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm new to Microsoft Sync Framework and trying to synchronize an SQlite database with Sql Server, any good links ?

Comment: If you got solution for this, can you provide help ? I am having same scenario. I am new to Sync Framework and I want to sync SQLite with SQL Server. Thanks

Comment: In fact it was a headache to implement a provider for Sqlite so i just moved my database to SQL Server compact edition its well supported by Sync Fx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no out-of-the-box sync provider for Sqlite, so you have to write your own.

or you can have a look at these links:

[Synchronization with SQLite on WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/02/19/synchronization-with-sqlite-on-winrt.aspx)

[SYNCHRONIZING WINRT/SQLITE USING SYNC FRAMEWORK TOOLKIT](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/synchronizing-winrtsqlite-using-sync-framework-toolkit/)

even if you're not building a WinRT app, you can modify the code to work in an ordinary desktop mode non WinRT type of app.

Comment: I found this project http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteclientsyn/, it's a Sqlite provider for ms sync, what do you think ?

Comment: that's for the older offline provider (sqlceclientsyncprovider/dbserversyncprovider/syncagent) combo. for simple hub-spoke sync, that might work.

Comment: have you an tutorial how to use it with source ?

Comment: is the two links above not enough? its not step by step, but tells you how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks, but it's different in the old way.