# update remote database with local database values of desktop application c#

Tags: c#, database

My desktop application stores all the data in local sqlite database,  when internet connection is available i want to sync all these local data into remote mysql database.  can anyone help me in this case

Comment: Hi, it is better to elaborate your question and post the code that you have tried, so that you will get more answers.

Comment: your question unclear. Both databases are SQLite ?

Comment: local database uses sqlite and remote is in mysql format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357646/getting-started-with-sync-framework-and-sqlite you may wanna take a look at this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this code

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace super
{

public partial class neworupload : Form
{
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"connection string");
    MySqlConnection conn;
    String connstring;
    public neworupload()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (connection == true)
        {
          //  MessageBox.Show("available");
            connstring = "SERVER=your ip;PORT=port;DATABASE=dbname;UID=userid;PASSWORD=password;SslMode = none;";
            try
            {
                //  con = new SQLiteConnection();
                con.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection success");
                String qu = "select * from users ";
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qu, con);
                SQLiteDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (data.Read())
                {


                    String a = data["iduser"].ToString();
                    String b = data["name"].ToString();
                    String c = data["type"].ToString();
                    String d = data["email"].ToString();
                    String f = data["hash"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                    Console.WriteLine(b);
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                    conn = new MySqlConnection();
                    conn.ConnectionString = connstring;
                    conn.Open();
                    String qudemo = "select iduser from users";

                    Console.WriteLine("dddd" + qudemo);
                    if(qudemo)

                    String qu1 = "INSERT INTO users(iduser,name,type,email,hash) Values(@iduser,@name,@type,@email,@hash)";



                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(qu1, conn);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iduser", a);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", b);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", c);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", d);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", f);

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(qu1);

                    conn.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check connectivity and try again!");
        }

    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is total logical, there is no magic to do this automatically.|
You need to take care of new added, updated, deleted records on remote or local. 
It is batter to write a central layer where from all the transactions should go and update a counter against each transaction and track them. 
It depends on the logic which you implement. You can achieve this by different ways. 
Like:
You can write a mapper which will get last value updated in value on remote DB and match in local, the insert or update the latest values from local to remote on the base of lat updated value in remote DB. 
Again it depend what you want to do and how.